# US State and Federal representatives by zip

Tags: web-services, geolocation

Is there a web-service/API that will provide information on who the US State and Federal representatives are by zip+4?

Comment: the 'zip' tag is not accurate. I can't think of what the correct tag would be, though, so Im thinking that this might not be the right forum for such a question.

Comment: I have attempted to fix the tags.

Comment: Are you programming anything or are you just wanting a government white pages?

Comment: Undid my undoing of Greg Hewgill's edit, since my change was a subset of his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will show most of the elected officials for a given zip + 4:
http://www.votesmart.org/search.php?search=11111-1111

Here is the web service API for VoteSmart (This should accomplish what you need): http://www.votesmart.org/services_api.php

Comment: Ideally a web service, but I could screen-scrap if worst comes to worse.

Answer (score 1):

http://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/01/08/introducing-the-congress-api/

Answer (score 0):

We used a feed from [Stateside](http://www.stateside.com/) that gave representatives and their information. You may want to look there.